# Corollaries of algebraic independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The numbers
$$\pi,e^{\pi},\Gamma (1/4)$$
are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is a corollary of the fact that
$$\frac{3}{\pi},3\frac{\Gamma (1/4)^8}{(2\pi)^6},e^{-2\pi}$$
are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't understand why the second result implies the first one.

Nestrenko, who proved this result in 1996, is using some facts about polynomials I'm unable to prove. For example, is it true that: if $P(x,y)=0$ for some polynomial $P$ in two variables with rational coefficients, then $Q(x,y^8)=0$ for some polynomial $Q$ in two variables with rational coefficients? If so, why?

For example, suppose that
$$P(x,y)=x^2-xy+y=0.$$
Repeatedly raising the left-hand side to the $8$th power doesn't seem to lead to any polynomial in $x,y^8$.

Comment: Yes, it's true, although the polynomial $Q$ is not so trivial to construct. This follows from basic facts about transcendence degree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_extension#Transcendence_basis

Comment: Actually I guess it's not so bad to describe explicitly. If $P(x, y) = 0$ then $Q(x, y^2) = P(x, y) P(x, -y) = 0$ is a vanishing polynomial in $x$ and $y^2$. For eighth powers you need to use eighth roots of unity, or equivalently repeat this construction three times. But basic facts about transcendence degree imply much more general results than this, e.g. that we can find $Q$ such that $Q(f(x, y), g(x, y)) = 0$ for any $f, g$.